# D3.js Line Chart Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="MNaN,NaNLNaN

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been following a tutorial to create a line chart with D3.js.

I follow the tutorial but I get an error of Error: Invalid value for `<path>` attribute d="MNaN,NaNLNaN.......

I don't know why this is happening!

```
    var formCumActual1 = parseFloat($('input[name="cumActual1"]').val());
    var formCumActual2 = parseFloat($('input[name="cumActual2"]').val());
    var formCumActual3 = parseFloat($('input[name="cumActual3"]').val());
    etc...


//Data for Line Chart

    var cumActualObject = [

        {
            "xNum": 1,
            "yNum": formCumActual1
        },
        {
            "xNum": 2,
            "yNum": formCumActual2
        },
        {
            "xNum": 3,
            "yNum": formCumActual3
        },
        etc...


   //Line Charts

var lineVis = d3.select("#lineChart"),
    WIDTH = 1000,
    HEIGHT = 500,
    MARGINS = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 20,
        left: 50
    },

    xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([d3.min(cumActualObject, function(d){
        return d.x
    }), d3.max(cumActualObject, function(d){
        return d.x
    })]),

    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(cumActualObject, function(d){
        return d.y
    }), d3.max(cumActualObject, function(d){
        return d.y
    })]),

    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale),

    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");


lineVis.append("svg:g").attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")").call(xAxis);

lineVis.append("svg:g").attr("transform", "translate(" +(MARGINS.left) + ",0)").call(yAxis);



var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d){
    return xScale(d.xNum);
})
.y(function(d){
    return yScale(d.yNum);
});


lineVis.append('svg:path')
.attr('d', lineGen(cumActualObject))
.attr('stroke', 'green')
.attr('stroke-width', 2)
.attr('fill', 'none');
```

Comment: what are values of formCumActual1, formCumActual2, formCumActual3? They should be either integers or floats.

Comment: So I have them being entered from a form and then all this code executes on the submit.

The values are decimals(floating integers) i.e: 0.9097726534, -0.1571913607..etc

Comment: check my answer. See if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the data like this

```
var cumActualObject = [

        {
            "xNum": 1,
            "yNum": formCumActual1
        },
        {
            "xNum": 2,
            "yNum": formCumActual2
        },
        {
            "xNum": 3,
            "yNum": formCumActual3
        }]
```

And find max min values like this

```
   xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([d3.min(cumActualObject, function(d){
        return d.x
    }), d3.max(cumActualObject, function(d){
        return d.x;//this is incorrect there is no x but it should be xNum
    })]),

    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(cumActualObject, function(d){
        return d.y//this is incorrect there is no x but it should be yNum
    }), d3.max(cumActualObject, function(d){
        return d.y//this is incorrect there is no x but it should be yNum
    })]),
```

Correct code should have been:

```
 xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([d3.min(cumActualObject, function(d){
        return d.xNum
    }), d3.max(cumActualObject, function(d){
        return d.xNum
    })]),

    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(cumActualObject, function(d){
        return d.yNum
    }), d3.max(cumActualObject, function(d){
        return d.yNum
    })]),
```

On calculate you must clear old graph other wise two graph will come on top of one another:

```
lineVis.selectAll("g").remove();//remove all g 
lineVis.selectAll("path").remove();//rmove all path
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/62WLwxPI5QLzaxTd0QI3?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This was excellent thank you!

Your code displays negative numbers correctly but mine doesn't. Not sure why. I've made the max and min changes.